# python request cookie expire date format

Tags: python, cookies

are using the python module requests to send a receive cookies for a webpage for login. I retreive the cookie but when i post it back, the expire date format seem incorret...any tips?

```
import requests
urlDelete = "https://10.10.7.5/nf/alerts"

urlLogin = "https://10.10.7.5/LOGIN"
params = {'credential_0': 'xxx', 'credential_1': 'xyxy',
          'destination': '//', 'login': 'Log In'}
r = requests.post(urlLogin, data=params, verify=False)
r2 = requests.post(urlDelete, verify=False, cookies=r.cookies)
print(r2)
print(r2.headers)
```

My Cookie values:

```
<bound method RequestsCookieJar.values of <RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='Mercury::Handler::AuthCookieHandler_AMPAuth', value='5da5f9149b26c08ecaa721a95328962a', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='10.10.7.5', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=True, expires=1425781296, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>>
```

my header response:

```
{'Cache-control': 'no-cache,max-age=30,must-revalidate',
 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
 'Content-Length': '3780',
 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
 'Date': 'Sun, 08 Feb 2015 01:13:23 GMT',
 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=15, max=100',
 'Pragma': 'no-cache',
 'Server': 'Apache',
 'Set-Cookie': 'Mercury::Handler::AuthCookieHandler_AMPAuth=; expires=Mon, 21-May-1971 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure;HttpOnly, Mercury::Handler::AuthCookieHandler_AMPAuth=; expires=Mon, 21-May-1971 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure;HttpOnly',
 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',
 'X-CONTENT-TYPE-OPTIONS': 'nosniff',
 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN'}
```

Comment: The server is invalidating the cookie. *Why* it is invalidating the cookie is not known, perhaps the server doesn't think your login is valid? Perhaps the login form contains an extra CSRF token you need to include in the form post? And why manually copy across `r.cookies` when one can use a [session object](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) instead?

Comment: Yes i have tried the session object also, same problem. The login is ok returna 200. Also this working using curl. With same parameters.

Comment: A 200 response is normal with form-based logins. Can you share the curl commands? Servers are black boxes, for all you know the server special-cases curl requests by looking at the user-agent header for example.

Comment: ´curl -q -k -c cookie2 -d "credential_0=xxxx" -d "credential_1=yyyy" -d "destination=/" -d "login=Log In" https://10.10.7.5/LOGIN
curl -k -b cookie2 https://10.10.7.5/nf/alerts´

Comment: Your Python code sends *two* slashes, curl just one, for `destination`

Comment: Yeah thats right else i dont get the cookie in return so.

Comment: i can do two slashes on the curl also and it works. The problem seems to be how the cookie is sent back to the server. as the unix timestamp received back from the cookie is correct, but the header response says others...

Comment: also if i do a get it works, but when trying to post it not works.

Comment: Right, because your **second `curl` command uses GET**, not POST.